# Save web scraped result to txt files by names

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I scraped a list of professor contact information from a school website, and now I want to save them individually by name, each name txt file contains their email, tel and office.
[ideal outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8Dti.png)

Currently my code is

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
url = 'https://www.cb.cityu.edu.hk/is/people/academic.html'
webpage = requests.get(url)
page = bs(webpage.content, 'html.parser')

#define list
name_list = []
phone_list = []
email_list = []
result = page.find_all('div', attrs = {'class': 'staff-details'})
for person in result:
    print(person.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop to fetch the data and simultaneously save the data in a text file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
url = 'https://www.cb.cityu.edu.hk/is/people/academic.html'
webpage = requests.get(url)
page = bs(webpage.content, 'html.parser')
prof_list = page.select(".staff-details")


for i in prof_list:
    name = i.select_one('.name >a').text
    email = i.select_one('.list-info div.value:nth-child(2) > a').text
    phone = i.select_one('.list-info div.value:nth-child(4)').text
    office = i.select_one('.list-info div.value:nth-child(6)').text

    with open(name+'.txt', 'w+') as file:
        file.write("Email:\n")
        file.write(email)
        file.write('\nPhone:\n')
        file.write(phone)
        file.write("\nOffice\n")
        file.write(office)
```

Comment: thank you bu i receive error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'?

Comment: I changed "email = i.select_one('.list-info div.value:nth-child(2) > a').text" text to value, and it returns 'none', and in the "file.write('\nPhone:\n')" line i got "write() argument must be str, not None"

Comment: You can use email in try block.
try:
     email .. ..
except:
     email = "Not Available"

Comment: and please if you find the answer correct please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Open file with name you want using context manager in w+ mode
here is a sample code for you

```
---> Inside Your For Loop
with open(file_name_come_here,"w+") as f :
      f.write(content_come_here_as_string)
```

Comment: Sorry I'm confused, I don't have a file in this program, just web scraping. or does this code create a file?

Comment: Yes this code will create a file with fileName you want and you can write anything into that file, also you should open that file with append mode so that you can write to file iteratively without loosing any progress